# What is correct variable in a flow to store a big JSON string

Tags: json, power-automate, microsoft-flow

I have a JSON file and need to copy and paste it to a variable in MS flow, what is the best variable for doing this?
I prefer not to call an API to read a file.

Comment: Is this the static JSON content or you are fetching this JSON from any data source like SharePoint?

Comment: This is a static JSON, I need to paste this Json from a file (i.e. not read the file,  a simple copy paste) to a MS flow variable, Thanks Ganesh

Comment: I think you should use variable of type "Object" in "Initialize variable" action in flow.

Comment: Thx, Do you what the max length of an "Object" variable is? I cannot find any document about it? nothing here: https://sharepains.com/2018/04/30/microsoft-flow-this-is-the-limit/   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/limits-and-config